# After toggling div with Jquery make it stay visible

Tags: javascript, hover, jquery

I have this jquery code:

http://jsfiddle.net/y8wPw/60/

All I want is that after DIV with content opens, it must stay visible, so that I can go over it and  use this div as a form( or some other purpose). But now, if I make a MOUSEOUT from Content div , it disappears.

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".body").hover(function () {
        $(".desc").toggle();
    })
})
```

Comment: Toggle will always switch between 'show' and 'hide'. You may just use .show()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".body").hover(function () {
        $(".desc").show();
    })
    $(".close").click(function () {
        $(".desc").hide();
    })
    $(".wrap").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".desc").hide();
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y8wPw/74/

This is what i was looking for! With some of your help i managed to make it!

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".body").hover(function () {
    $(".desc").show();
})
```

})

Answer (score 1):

Why not try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".body").hover(function () {
        $(".desc").show();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your js fiddle code by adding a wrapper and assigning the event to it.
I guess that fixes you problem :)

updated the html to

```
<div id="wrap">
<div class="body">Hellp</div>
<div class="desc">Any content here!</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

updated the css

```
#wrap{overflow:hidden}
```

updated the js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wrap").hover(function () {
        $(".desc").toggle();
    })
})
```

The link http://jsfiddle.net/RUtgE/1/

Comment: Add the code and the link to the edited fiddle in the answer please, otherwise it is a bit hard or impossible to find which revision of the fiddle you saved, let alone the code would be lost if/when jsfiddle stops working.

Comment: Content DIV appears even if i go with mouse next to the HELP div... Check again

Answer (score 0):

Use `.css('display', 'block')` instead of `.toggle()`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sohelkhalifa/y8wPw/61/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouseenter instead of hover. In this case it will show the first time you go over the "help" button, the next time it will close again.

Check out http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/ for more mouse events to play with!